# Swagger routing not consistent on Servicestack

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

I've just added Swagger to servicestack app.

I access it via /api/swagger-ui, but it then tries to call its dependant js and css files from /api/lib and /api/css/ respectively. The app 404s on all these files.

On a previously implementation it would have got these files from /api/swagger-ui/lib and /api/swagger-ui/css.

Is this a deliberate change? or a bug that has crept in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the / suffix, i.e /api/swagger-ui/. You can find the correct URL for the Swagger UI by clicking on the "Swagger UI" link in the /metadata page.